# Parented object constrained within parent object

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I have one smaller object that is inside of another, it's parented and the larger object completely envelopes the smaller. I've parented the smaller object to the larger object's bones so when I pose it, the smaller object moves with it. How do I make it so that all parts of the smaller object stay INSIDE of the larger object and that it all moves together.

[image]

Images attached to show what I'm referring to.